# Doctrine2 schema tool update fail on many to many relationship

Tags: exception, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, many-to-many, database-schema

When I need to update my database structure, I do it in PHP using this kind of code :

```php
$tool = new SchemaTool($em);
$classes = array(
    $em->getClassMetadata('Entities\Entity1'), 
    $em->getClassMetadata('Entities\Entity2')
);
$tool->updateSchema($classes);
```

It works fine until a many to many relation is defined. Consider the following entities as an example :

```php
/**
 * Entities\CET\User
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="tb_user")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
     * @JoinTable(name="users_groups")
     */
    private $groups;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

```php
/**
 * Entities\CET\Group
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="tb_group")
 */
class Group
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="groups")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

If my database is empty (no tables) and I update the structure, it works fine. But if tables are already created and I simply want to update them, it breaks and give me the following error :

> An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE tb_group CHANGE id
>   id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL': SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1833 Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key
>   constraint 'FK_FF8AB7E0FE54D947' of table 'example.users_groups'

I've tried to manually define join columns and set them to nullable, like this :

```php
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
 * @JoinTable(name="users_groups",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)}
 *      )
 */
private $groups;
```

without much success. Even the simpliest way to define the relation fail to update using Doctrine SchemaTool.

My current workaround is to delete all tables and re-create them, but it's an horrible "solution" on so many levels...

Comment: Doctrine is not perfect and sometimes has issues with foreign keys.
Rather then deleting all tables, try only deleting foreign key in `tb_group` table.

Comment: So you say there is no way of declaring the schema so the update will work without any manual intervention ? I've tried to only remove tables involved in the relation,  it works but it's almost the same as my previous workaround because thoses tables have other relations and re-importing their data can be a real difficulty..

Comment: Unless you fix it in Doctrine package on Github, there isn't.

Comment: Can you try declaring the variables as protected instead of private. I have read somewhere that while using reflection, doctrine will not clone the values of private variables. They recommend only the $id to be private since it should not be cloned.

Comment: I usually declare all properties as protected, I didn't notice $users and $groups were private. It doesn't change anything about the exception.